# Php Error - Unexpected require_once expecting function

Tags: php, php-include, medoo

I'm currently trying to fetch the medoo framework so that I can begin easily retrieving data from my MySQL database... and for some reason it doesn't work!

here's the code of my **signin.php** file

```
<?php
    function loginUserAccount($loginname, $password){
    // Include Medoo (configured)
    require_once 'medoo.min.php';

    // Initialize
    $database = new medoo();

    $email = $database->get('MM_Users', 'Email', [
        'ID' => 1
    ]);
    return $email;
    }
    ?>
```

And the error:

**Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected 'require_once' (T_REQUIRE_ONCE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in **/myfiledirectory/example.php** on line **4**

Any help is greatly appreciated! I'm not quite sure at what's going wrong.

The php file that's running is :

```
<?php
require_once('signin.php');
if(!loginUserAccount('bobby@gmail.com', 'AveryRandomPassword')){

    echo 'error';
} else {
    echo $email;
}
?>
```

There's also a difference in the wrapping for require_once... this doesn't make a difference does it? And if so, which one is more advisable to use in a production environment?

Comment: `require_once 'medoo.min.php';` `require_once('signin.php');` Spot the difference

Comment: You said your code is from the `signin.php` file, but the error you pasted says it's in `example.php`. If you didn't change the error text, what is on line 4 of `example.php`?

Comment: BTW, you can use `require_once` with or without the parentheses.

Comment: You say `the class` but I don't see any classes anywhere here

Comment: @myesain I obfuscated the file system directory, it is in fact pointing to the correct file.

Comment: @muffinjello If any of the answers were related to what you fixed then you should upvote and even accept one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have `require_once` inside a class without a function. 
That's the main reason.

Try putting the `require_once` in the `construct`.

To be exact :

```
class foo 
{
    require_once('bar.php');
}
```

will throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
require_once('signin.php');
```

is inside a class but outside a method, which is not possible in PHP.

Comment: Just in case the above is not clear - require_once CAN be used inside  methods/functions/constructors. You cannot use require_once to include the methods/functions themselves

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but doesn't require_once 'medoo.min.php'; require parentheses?
like so:
    require_once ('medoo.min.php');

Comment: No, and it's considered bad practice in general to use parentheses for language constructs like `require_once`, even though it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, its likely to work**

```
<?
    require_once 'medoo.min.php';
    use Medoo\Medoo; //If this line raises errors, remove it

    // Initialize DB
    $database = new Medoo(
    // required
    'database_type' => 'mysql',
    'database_name' => 'name',
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'your_username',
    'password' => 'your_password',
    );

    $email = $database->get('MM_Users', 'Email', [
        'ID' => 1
    ]);
      return $email;
    }
?>
```

One other bug I noticed is that you instantiated a the Medoo object (in other words, you called the Medoo class) using a Lowercase **M** of which shouldn't be the case. In addition remember to pass in the correct Database & Server values.

See [this](https://medoo.in/api/new) for more info if you're still facing challenges on that.