# How to load catalog model in admin controller

Tags: opencart

I am using Opencart Version 2.1.0.1, how to load frontend model in admin controller,

i have a model function which tells external booking id

```
class ModelShippingParcelled extends Model {
        public function getParcelledBooking($order_id) {
             $query = $this->db->query("SELECT booking_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "parcelled WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
             return $query->row;
    }
```

I want to load this model in admin controller. What is the best way to do this?
Should I rewrite this model in admin too? But I don't want to rewrite the same function. If there is a good way please suggest!

Comment: More often than not you'll end up needing some extra model functionality in the admin area, so just create an admin model with the duplicated code for now. That way it also follows the intended architecture (admin and catalog should be able to operate independent of each other)

Comment: @Mavelo *the intended architecture* – this is not "architecture", this is a joke. The only reason to *just create (…) duplicated code for now* is if one plans to migrate away from Opencart anyway, and one actually should.

Comment: this is one of my biggest griefs so far with opencart. They re-invent the wheel on autoloading and namespacing, diverting from 95% of the rest of the PHP-verse that follows PSR4 and builds composer/packagist compatible code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is one ugly trick to achieve what you want. Example if you want to use the frontend's catalog/product model from your admin controller, then you can:

```
require_once DIR_CATALOG . "model/catalog/product.php";
$product = new ModelCatalogProduct($this->registry);
```

This will work also when you want to use the admin model from the frontend controller, just change the `require` statement.

Comment: With this approach you might end with redeclarion fatal error, because all most in admin and catalog are named identically. But I agree, that its's the only solution besides copying or reproducing model functions directly.

Answer (score 2):

I also needed to call a function from `catalog/model` inside `admin/model` (without copying). [Requiring a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726288/php-error-unexpected-require-once-expecting-function) occured to be imposible in php.
But I figured out that I can move the function into `system/library`, for example in `/system/library/cart/cart.php`.
Albeit cart functions is never called in admin it occured to be possible. So I called it like

`$this->cart->functionName($params)`

To make sure function is still working in catalog I made replacement via shell like

`find catalog -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/this->model_catalog_filter->functionName/this->cart->functionName/g'`

edit: requiring function body from one common location should also work. I didn't test in production though:

```
public function functionName(){
    require_once DIR_ROOT.'path/to/function/body.php';
}
```

Comment: This is not bad, but bear in mind a function in system will have no access to the catalog models/controllers afaik

Comment: yes, thx. but if function does only database request you're good to go. btw you could probably require function body instead, I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you make a copy of the model in the admin folder.
And if you are sure which functions you are gonna use copy only them.

Comment: Bad idea. It's duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is use ajax to call the front end controller/model from the admin, adding some long string get or url based password if you dont want it run by users.